# What objects do I alloc/release

Tags: objective-c, alloc

in Objective-C and simply speaking - am I correct when assuming

1. that all pointer variables must be released when they're not used any more?
2. Every pointer variable (*) is a class of some kind, or not?
3. Every pointer variable therefore needs to be allocated and initialised using "alloc" and "init" (or similar)?
4. When declaring variales using Object methods I may not need "alloc" or "init"?
5. Number declarations (BOOL, int, float, etc) do not require memory management as long as they're not declared as a pointer?

Thanks for any advice helping to sort out my confusion
   iFloh

Answer (score 3):

> 1) that all pointer variables must be
>   released when they're not used any
>   more?

It depends if you "own" the pointed thing. I recommend you to carefully read these [Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) rules to learn how to release a pointer.

> 2) Every pointer variable (*) is a class
>   of some kind, or not?

Not every pointers. A pointer variable may hold a pointer to an object or to a block of memory. It is just a pointer to something.

> 3) Every pointer variable therefore needs
>   to be allocated and initialised using
>   "alloc" and "init" (or similar)?

Not every pointers. A pointer variable may hold a pointer to an object or to a block of memory. The pointed thing can be an already existing object or an allocated chunck of memory.

> 4) When declaring variales using Object
>   methods I may not need "alloc" or
>   "init"?

Not everytime. You may get a pointer to an existent object without knowing who allocated and initialized it. Again, there are some ownership rules to follow. I recommend you to carefully read these [Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) rules.

> 5) Number declarations (BOOL, int, float,
>   etc) do not require memory management
>   as long as they're not declared as a
>   pointer?

Yes. There are called primitive types, and as long as you manipulate them as value, you don't have to deal with their memory management.

Answer (score 2):

> *that all pointer variables must be released when they're not used any more?*

Only if the "pointer variable" points to an instance of an Objective-C class and only if you caused that instance to be retained previously.   [Read this: Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

> *Every pointer variable (* **) is a class of some kind, or not?*

If the pointer variable is declared as being a pointer to an instance of a class, then it will point to an instance of a class. Otherwise, it won't.   Pointers are exactly that; a pointer -- a reference -- to a chunk of memory.  That chunk of memory might be a class, an instance of a class, a C structure, or a raw buffer (or something else).

> *Every pointer variable therefore needs to be allocated and initialised using "alloc" and "init" (or similar)?*

Only if the pointer points to an instance of an Objective-C class.   If it is a C structure, you might use `malloc()`.   Even in the case of an Objective-C class, you might not `alloc` anything:

NSString *foo = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hello, %@", @"World!"];
NSString *bar = @"bar";
NSBundle *main = [NSBundle mainBundle];

(BTW:  None of the above need a `-release`.)

> *When declaring variales using Object methods I may not need "alloc" or "init"?*

This question indicates that you should go read -- and re-read (I read it about once every 18 months for the first decade I wrote Objective-C code, learning something each time) -- [the Objective-C language guide](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).

You should probably also read something about the C language itself.  That would likely help you to understand pointers vs. other types.

> *Number declarations (BOOL, int, float, etc) do not require memory management as long as they're not declared as a pointer?*

Yes, but it is much simpler than being type specific.  When you say `int foo;` you are telling the compiler to carve out a bit of space in the local scope -- on the stack, generally -- to store an int's worth of data.  When you say `int *foo;`, you are telling the compiler to carve out a bit of space in the local scope to store a pointer to -- to store the address of -- a location in memory that contains an int.

Thus, `NSArray *bar` is just a pointer to an instance and, yes, `NSArray bar;`, if it were not explicitly disallowed, would carve out a chunk of space on the stack to hold an NSArray instance.

When you have a pointer to something that something must be initialized somehow and that is often done through allocation (but not always).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct:

1. Yes.
2. I guess. I'm not sure I understand the question.
3. Kind of: as you said, it's not necessarily `alloc`+`init`, if you use certain Class methods. So, the allocation and initialization are done implicitly.
4. Correct. (see above)
5. I believe that it's more than numbers and that C primitives do not require memory management.

I'd recommend that you read the [memory management rules from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) as well as the [Stanford class on iPhone Programming](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/33).

Comment: 1 - incorrect.  2 - It is a c-ism.  3 - correct. 4 - correct.  5 - Sort of.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Good point on #1. It's not that I don't know that you don't release explicitly every time, it's that I took the question as "do the objects need to be released (implicitly by me or somewhere else)?" (as in with autoreleased objects). But that was a dumb way of reading the question :)