# How do I know if I need to alloc and if I need to release?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Completely new to Objective-C, trying to find out when I need to alloc and release objects.

For example, I want to fetch some data from the Web. I found [an article](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) at Apple which has this code:

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                  [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"]
                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                timeoutInterval:60.0];
// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] 
                                 initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

What I don't understand is: Why do they need to call alloc on the connection but not on the request? How do I know when I need alloc and when not?

Similar questions for release. From what I read, I only ever need to release objects that were initialized using alloc/init. But all "initWithXXX" functions return autoreleased objects instead.

Is this a hard rule, or just convention? Is there a way to find out if I need to release an object or not?

Comment: Many similar questions on SO already, see e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379800/what-objects-do-i-alloc-release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [*Memory Management Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). All of these are explained there. Also check out [*Learn Objective-C*](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/).

---

> Why do they need to call alloc on the connection but not on the request?

Whenever you need to own an object to make it live longer than the function's scope, the object needs to be `-retain`ed. Of course you could use

```
NSURLConnection* theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest
                                                               delegate:self];
```

but the connection will be `-autorelease`d. But because there's time for a connection to finish, this variable should be `-retain`ed to prevent the connection becoming invalid. Of course, then, you could do

```
NSURLConnection* theConnection = [[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest
                                                               delegate:self] retain];
```

But this is equivalent to `+alloc` → `-init` → `-autorelease` → `-retain`, the last two steps are redundant. Probably that's why Apple chooses to use `+alloc`/`-init` here.

(BTW, this style would cause the static analyzer to complain. It's better to store `theConnection` as an ivar somewhere, e.g. in the delegate object.)

On the other hand, the NSURLRequest is just a temporary object, so it needs to be `-release`d when the function ends.  Again, you could use

```
NSURLRequest* theRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:...];
...
[theRequest release];
```

this is even more efficient, as the autorelease pool won't be filled up, but using this method one may forget to `-release` and cause a leak.

> But all "initWithXXX" functions return autoreleased objects instead.

No, `-init…` should never return an `-autorelease`d object.

Comment: All three answers are really helpful, accepting this as it's the most complete one.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [Cocoa Memory Management guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html). You own an object only if the methods used to obtain it contains one of:

- `new`
- `alloc`
- `retain`
- `copy`

... and you only need to `release` (i.e. relinquish ownership) if you own it. If you obtain an instance through a method not containing any of these, you don't own it and have to take ownership explicitly (using `retain`) if you need it.

So, you need to `alloc` if you:

- want ownership or
- if there is no convenience constructor available (and you thus have to use `alloc`/`init`)

The initializer methods don't return autoreleased instances, they only *initialize* an `alloc`d instance.

Answer (score 1):

`initWithXXX:` methods *do not* return autoreleased objects! `somethingWithXXX:` class methods, however, do. This *is* a convention (in that it's not compiler-enforced), but it's followed so closely that you can treat it as a hard rule. The Clang static analyzer will also complain if you don't follow it.

`requestWithURL:` doesn't have "init" in the name. Also, `requestWithURL:` is called on the `NSURLRequest` class, whereas `initWithRequest:delegate:` is called on the `NSURLConenction` object returned by calling `alloc` on the `NSURLConnection` class.

(I hope that all makes sense.)